# Print selected rows from HTML table

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I have table which looks like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1cvfee0d/)
Now i need to implement functionality to print just selected rows. Rows can be selected by clicking on check-box on the right of each row.
Can somebody advise me how to complete it, please?

I already implemented full table printing functionality with

```
var divToPrint=document.getElementById("pretazna");
   newWin= window.open("");
   newWin.document.write(divToPrint.outerHTML);
   newWin.print();
   newWin.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code... it doesn't create a popup window but instead hides rows using a print stylesheet ([demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/1cvfee0d/1/))

CSS

```
@media print {
  #print, tfoot, tbody tr:not(.printme) {
    display: none !important;
  }
}
```

Javascript

```
function matches(el, selector) {
  // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/matches
  var matches = document.querySelectorAll(selector),
    i = matches.length;
  while (--i >= 0 && matches.item(i) !== el) {}
  return i > -1;
}

function closest(el, selector) {
  while (el && !matches(el, selector)) {
    el = el.parentNode;
  }
  return matches(el, selector) ? el : null;
}

document.querySelector('table').addEventListener('change', function(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  closest(target, 'tr').classList[target.checked ? 'add' : 'remove']('printme');
})

document.querySelector("#print").addEventListener('click', function() {
  window.print();
});
```